# how to get the xml from server & show into the tree in extjs?

Tags: xml, extjs

I am using Extjs 3.4.0
I want to get the xml from the server side like below example.
example:
`<Root>
    <I DN:'abc'/>
    <I DN:'def'/>
</Root>`

then, I want to show this DN column in the tree.

how can i proceed to do this?

Till now, i have used only static data to show in the tree. but now i want this tree nodes from the xml data.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.